# Double buffer vs double array c++

Tags: c++, buffer, multidimensional-array

I was asked to create a matrix with 5 rows and unknown column.
And my boss want me to use a 1 dimensional buffer. concatenated by 5 rows buffer.
I don't get what is that mean, can some one provide me a simple example please!

With array I can do

```
double[][] arr = new double[5][someNumber];
```

But he says then the size would be limited.

So I don't know what he means by using a DOUBLE buffer, I am not very good @C++

Thank you very much, an example would be nice!

Comment: ['Double buffering'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering) is a reference to an I/O technique or a computer graphics technique, and not to a buffer or array of type `double`.  Also, C is not C++, and using `new` like that means strictly C++.

Answer (score 1):

For `R` rows and `C` columns declare `double arr[R * C]`, and `arr[i * C + j]` is the element at cell `[i, j]`.

This generalizes to arbitrary dimensions.

Flattening out an array like that can be a very useful optimization, especially when you use dynamic arrays such as `std::vector`, where you can get a single dynamic array rather than one for each row.

Comment: but this is array isn't it, I am talking about buffer

Comment: @LanNguyen "Buffer" is a use pattern, not a data type.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras So when you do this, are you creating a 2D array, or 1D, it looks 2D to me.

Comment: @LanNguyen It's a 1D array. The arithmetics provided by Kerrek tell you how to "emulate" a 2D array inside this 1D array. Where you previously wrote `arr[i][j]`, you now write `arr[arr * C + j]` instead.

Comment: ah interesting, i didn't know this, thanks, let me touch up with my boss on this

Comment: talked to my boss and he used something like this: let say array 3x4: int array = null*; array=(double*)malloc(3*4*sizeof(double)); so how can i index into specific row and column in such buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're saying

```
double *arr[5];
for(unsigned int x = 0; x < 5; ++x)
{
       arr[x] = new double[someNumber];
}
```

Since, you know that you have 5 for sure, and an unknown part my assumption is this is how you're referring to it.

Comment: so to me, this is an array of pointer, and each of the pointer point to the beginning of a row, am i correct?

Comment: It is. More or less this is the equivalent of the *assumption* of `arr[5][];` `arr[0]` will point to some address, which will be the size of `someNumber` double's.

Comment: yeah this is what I thought of too, thank you for your clarification.